# Meteor, properly rendering HTML within a cursor.forEach

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I am coming over from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041451/meteor-callback-when-a-template-has-been-re-rendered)

Currently I have this code which is adapted from the mentioned post.

```
Template.messages.rendered = ->
    this.autorun( (c) ->
        document.bottomCheck = false
        if null != chatDiv and chatDiv.scrollTop + chatDiv.offsetHeight >= chatDiv.scrollHeight
            document.bottomCheck = true
        $("#chat-box").empty()
        messageCursor = Messages.find({}, {sort: {time: 1}})
        messageCursor.forEach((message) ->
            makeMessage(message) // Uses jQuery to insert HTML into our page
        )   
        Deps.afterFlush(() ->
            setScrollToBottom() if document.bottomCheck
        )   
    )
```

This is working great to log each message every time new messages come in. The part I am confused about, is how to I populate my HTML with the proper data? I currently have the following HTML which calls a template helper to render my messages.

```
<template name="messages" class="message-style">
    <div id="chat-box">
        {{#each getMessages}}
            <div class="chat-message" id="chat-message-scroll" style="background-color: {{backgroundColor}}">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 message-name">
                        <div class="chat-message-name">{{name}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 message-contents">
                        <!-- <br> -->
                        <div class="chat-message-contents" style="color:{{textColor}}">{{{convertMsg message}}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 message-timestamp">
                        <span class="chat-message-timestamp">

                            {{#if notSystemMsg this.type}}
                                {{#if isBookmarked this._id}}
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" id='chat-full-bookmark'></i>
                                {{else}}
                                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" id='chat-empty-bookmark'></i>
                                {{/if}}
                            {{/if}}
                            {{convertToLocalTime time}}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I just would like to how how I can adapt what I currently have to take advantage of the new way I am getting my messages data? Do I just create and insert DOM elements programatically? My issue with that is that it doesn't seem like the meteor way of doing things because I wouldn't be using blaze or spacebars.

Any help on this issue would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT** Old `getMessages` helper

```
Template.messages.getMessages = () ->
    ... # Random Logic
    allMessages = Messages.find({}, {sort: {time: -1 }}).fetch()
    ... # Messing with allMessages before returning to the helper
```

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place? You can create another cursor for HTML rendering.

Comment: Im sorry, Im not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Could you show us the code of the `getMessage` helper?

Comment: I added a very small portion of the `getMessages` helper. There is a bunch of logic in there that we use to alter the objects, but nothing too fancy. The reason Im trying to change this is to take advantage of the `Deps.afterFlush` that is mentioned in the post that I linked too.

Comment: @apendua, Is there anything else I could provide that might help you help me? Currently we are using the top code block for our solution, and I will include more code to show what we are doing, but it's a less than ideal solution and I think it's clear to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if your helper returned `allMessages` cursor, and not just an array. If you need to modify the documents before rendering HTML you can use the `transform` function as described [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#find).

Comment: Whats the value in this? Is there some advantage to returning a cursor instead of an array?

Comment: Of course, there is! When you use cursor along with `each` Meteor is smart enough to apply very grained updates to your rendered content. So things like reordering/adding/removing elements will only require as little updates as possible. If you used array instead and removed a single element, the whole list would need to be rerendered.

Comment: I know that was true with Spark, but is it still an issue with Blaze?

Comment: Yes, [it is still true](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/blaze/builtins.js#L74). Though, Blaze may deal a little nicer with the array case when you compare it to Spark. Anyways, there's no need to use arrays if only you can use cursor.